# Hacer que el programa se vuelva a repetir y mostrar otra vez el menú de selección

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer que el programa se vuelva a repetir y mostrar otra vez el menú de selección, pero no sé cómo hacer para que retorne hasta el switch opc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int opc,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,notafinal,a;
char op2;

///sistema de menu para seleccionar la accion///
cout<<"........MENU DE ESTUDIANTE............."<<endl;
cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Revisar nota.................(1)"<<endl;
cout<<"Nota primer bimestre.........(2)"<<endl;
cout<<"Nota segundo bimestre........(3)"<<endl;
cout<<"Nota tercer bimestre.........(4)"<<endl;
cout<<"Nota cuarto bimestre.........(5)"<<endl;
cin>>opc;


switch(opc)
{
///elegir y realizar la accion///
case 1: cout<<"Su nota es de = "<<notafinal<<endl;
break;

case 2: cout<<"Ingrese la primera nota del estudiante = "; cin>>nota1;
notafinal= nota1+notafinal;
cout<<endl<<"La nota del estudiante es de = "<<notafinal<<endl; 
break;

case 3: cout<<"Ingrese la segunda nota del estudiante = "; cin>>nota2;
notafinal= nota2+notafinal;
cout<<endl<<"La nota del estudiante es de = "<<notafinal<<endl;
break;

case 4: cout<<"Ingrese la tercera nota del estudiante = "; cin>>nota3;
notafinal= nota3+notafinal;
cout<<endl<<"La nota del estudiante es de = "<<notafinal<<endl;
break;

case 5: cout<<"Ingrese la cuarta nota del estudiante = "; cin>>nota4;
notafinal= nota4+notafinal;
cout<<endl<<"La nota del estudiante es de = "<<notafinal<<endl;
break;
default:{
    cout<<"Ingrese un valor correcto"<<endl;
}
 //fin del primer menú//
```

aqui tengo que volver a mostrar todo para seguir añadiendo notas hasta que yo decida acabar el programa

```
}

//volver o salir del menú//
do
    {
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Desea realizar algun otro cambio (S)(N): ";
    cin>>op2;
    
    switch(op2)
    {
        case 's':
        case 'S':;break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':break;
        default: cout<<endl<<"Ingrese un valor correcto"<<endl;;
    } 
    
    
    
system("pause");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Soy yo o falta el `while` para completas el `do`?

Comment: si pero no se que poner en el while para que se repita todo

Comment: Crea una opción que sea para salir del programa, por ejemplo asociado al número 0, y pones `while ( !(opc==0) )`. De este modo, si la opción elegida es `0`, en el caso que te digo es la opción de SALIR, pues saldrá del bucle. En caso contrario, vuelve a pintar todo.

Comment: Podrías utilizar un for infinito, ```
for(;;) { ... } ```

Comment: @Londo pon eso como respuesta, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    enum op {VER_NOTA=1,PRIMER_BIMESTRE,SEGUNDO_BIMESTRE,TERCER_BIMESTRE,CUARTO_BIMESTRE,SALIR};
    int opc = 0, nota1 = 0, nota2 = 0, nota3 = 0, nota4 = 0, notafinal = 0;
    bool control;

    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"........MENU DE ESTUDIANTE............."<<endl;
        cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Revisar nota.................(1)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nota primer bimestre.........(2)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nota segundo bimestre........(3)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nota tercer bimestre.........(4)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nota cuarto bimestre.........(5)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Salir del menu...............(6)"<<endl;

        do{
            control = false;
            cout<<endl<<"Opcion: ";
            cin>>opc;

            switch(opc){
                case VER_NOTA:
                    cout<<endl<<"Nota final = "<<notafinal<<endl<<endl;
                    cout<<"Presione una tecla para continuar. . .";
                    getch();
                    break;

                case PRIMER_BIMESTRE:
                    cout<<endl<<"Ingrese nota primer bimestre: ";
                    cin>>nota1;
                    notafinal = nota1 + notafinal;
                    break;

                case SEGUNDO_BIMESTRE:
                    cout<<endl<<"Ingrese nota segundo bimestre: ";
                    cin>>nota2;
                    notafinal = nota2 + notafinal;
                    break;

                case TERCER_BIMESTRE:
                    cout<<endl<<"Ingrese nota tercer bimestre: ";
                    cin>>nota3;
                    notafinal = nota3 + notafinal;
                    break;

                case CUARTO_BIMESTRE:
                    cout<<endl<<"Ingrese nota primer bimestre: ";
                    cin>>nota4;
                    notafinal = nota4 + notafinal;
                    break;

                case SALIR:
                    break;

                default:
                    cout<<"- Opcion invalida"<<endl;
                    control = true;
                    break;
            }
        }while(control);
    }while(opc != SALIR);

    return 0;
}
```